# C/C++ Обход бинарного дерева в ширину

Tags: c++, c, очередь, бинарное-дерево, fifo

Я новичок, но я  бы очень хотел разобраться, как это работает, поэтому буду весьма признателен, если Вы мне подскажите те моменты, которые я не понимаю..
(Да, мне необходимо разобраться в чужом коде, но я действительно хочу понять, что к чему.)

```
typedef struct node {
    const void*  ptr;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t* head;
    node_t* tail;
} queue_t;

typedef struct tree {
    int  key;
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
} tree_t;
```

1-е узел очереди (для чего нужен `const void*  ptr;`?Почему именно `const void*`..), 2-е очередь для обхода дерева в ширину, 3-е -двоичное дерево поиска.

```
 void  queue_init(queue_t* q){ q->head = q->tail = NULL; }
 int   queue_empty(queue_t* q) { return (q->head == NULL); }
```

Что значит вот эта функция?Вроде с предыдущими двумя более менее понятно..Одна из них инициализирует очередь, другая - проверка на пустую очередь..Но эта?..

```
const void* queue_front(queue_t* q) { return q->head->ptr; }
```

Далее..добавление в очередь.Тут я конкретно запутался (`queue_t* q` и `node_t* p` - что значат буквы q и p после указателей, связанных с вышеописанными структурами?)Да еще и поиттер (`ptr` ) ..как это работает? :(

```
int queue_push(queue_t* q, const void* ptr){
    node_t* p = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(p != NULL){
        p->ptr  = ptr;
        p->next = NULL;
        if(q->head == NULL)
            q->head = q->tail = p;
        else {
            q->tail->next = p;
            q->tail = p;
        }
    }
    return (p != NULL);
}
```

Удаление из очереди.Тут вроде всё понятно для меня.

```
void queue_pop(queue_t* q){
    node_t* t;
    if(q->head != NULL){
        t       = q->head;
        q->head = q->head->next;
        free(t);
        if(q->head == NULL)
            q->tail = NULL;
    }
}
```

Самая важная часть программы.Функция обхода дерева в ширину.Я к сожалению, не совсем понимаю, как должен работать данный алгоритм, даже смотря на функции, поэтому, если вы можете объяснить, как он осуществляется, было бы здорово..Т.е. сам принцип.

```
void tree_out_width(FILE* _out, const tree_t* tr){
    const tree_t* p;
    queue_t q;
    queue_init(&q);
 
    queue_push(&q, tr);
    while(! queue_empty(&q)){
        p = (const tree_t*)queue_front(&q);
        queue_pop(&q);
        fprintf(_out, "%d ",p->key);
        
        if(p->left != NULL)
            queue_push(&q, p->left);
        if(p->right != NULL)
            queue_push(&q, p->right);
    }
}
```

Я не совсем понял, почему моя закоменченная реализация оказалось не правильной, был бы рад объяснению.

```
tree_t* tree_insert(tree_t** tr, int key){
/*  if (*tr == NULL){
        *tr = (tree_t*)malloc(sizeof(tree_t));
        *tr->p=key;
        *tr->left=NULL;
        *tr->right=NULL;
        return p;
    }
    else{
        if(key>=*tr->p){
            tree_insert(*tr->right,key);
        }
        else tree_insert(*tr->left,key);
    }
}*/
    tree_t* p = *tr;
    while(p != NULL){
        if(key < p->key){
            tr = &p->left;
            p  = p->left;
        } 
        else {
            tr = &p->right;
            p  = p->right;
        }
    }
    p = (tree_t*)malloc(sizeof(tree_t));
    if(p != NULL){
        p->key  = key;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
        *tr = p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

С функцией очистки дерева вопросов нет.

```
void tree_clear(tree_t* tr){
    if(tr != NULL){
        if(tr->left != NULL)
            tree_clear(tr->left);
        if(tr->right != NULL)
            tree_clear(tr->right);
        free(tr);
    }
}
```

И сам мэйн.

```
int main(){
    tree_t* tr = NULL;
    int n , fir, el, t, i;
    printf ("enter number of elements in the tree :");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    printf ("enter the root :");
    scanf ("%d",&fir);
    tr = tree_insert(&tr, fir);
    for (i=1; i<n;i++){
        scanf ("%d",&el);
        t = el;
        tree_insert(&tr, t);
    }
    printf ("\n");
 
    tree_out_width(stdout, tr);
    tree_clear(tr);
    return 0;
}
```

Программа работает корректно.Не кидайтесь тапками, заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Смысл обхода в ширину проще всего понять в сравнении с обходом в глубину. Нарисуйте на листочке какой-нибудь граф (лучше — дерево, корень которого сверху и вниз идут листья, так наглядней получается). Теперь начините с корневой вершины. Перейдите к любой дочерней ветке. Затем перейдите к любой дочерней ветке этой ветки и так далее. Так вы окажетесь в самом низу дерева. Теперь поднимайтесь на верх, берите первый соседний не посещенный узел и снова спускайтесь вниз. Это будет **поиск в глубину**.

Comment: А вот если бы вы сначала проверили первый дочерний узел корня, потом следующий, следующий, потом перешли бы на дочерние узлы этих дочерних узлов и так далее, то это был бы **поиск в ширину**. На листочке даже визуально будет понятно, что в первом случае вы уходите вглубь дерева, в самый низ, а во втором — в ширину.

Comment: У вас в одном вопросе намешано сразу несколько. Задайте несколько отдельных вопросов — один про дерево, другой — про очередь и так далее.

Comment: @eanmos Просто тут всё взаимосвязано, именно поэтому не хотел разбивать вопрос из-за этого..Может, на некоторые получу ответ ;)

Comment: @eanmos Про обходы..спасибо за подробное объяснение, но это я понимаю.Сама реализация немного непонятна.Мы ставим корень(узел) в очередь..Потом p присваиваем значение корня(узла)?[тут мне не очень понятно, потому что я не разобрался с функцией queue_front)..Потом выталкиваем его.Выводим p .А затем посещаем его ветки(если они не пустые) и их тоже добавляем в очередь.Так?Или как-то иначе?

Comment: А, я вопрос невнимательно прочитал :) У вас функция `queue_front` позволяет получить первый элемент в очереди. Ваша очередь может хранить любые элементы, поэтому тип `ptr` в структуре `node` — это `const void *`. В функции `tree_out_width` ваша очередь используется для хранения узлов дерева, поэтому, когда мы получаем очередной элемент очереди мы выполняем каст к структуре `tree_t *`: `p = (const tree_t*)queue_front(&q);`.

Comment: Дальше мы этот элемент из очереди выкидываем (`queue_pop`), а затем печатаем его в файл `fprintf(_out, "%d ",p->key);`. На этом обработка конкретной вершины завершена, она нам больше не нужна. Дальше мы добавляем в очередь сначала левый дочерний узел, а потом правый и так, пока у нас очередь полностью не опустеет.

Comment: Т. е. когда мы вызываем функцию обхода сначала в очередь добавляется корень. Потом мы проверяем, не пуста ли очередь. Если нет, выталкиваем из нее первый элемент (это у нас сейчас корень, который мы только что добавили) и печатаем его в файл, а затем добавляем в очередь левый дочерний узел, а потом правый. Затем снова проверяем, не пуста ли очередь. Если она не пуста, то снова выталкиваем первый элемент (этим элементом будет левый дочерний узел корня, который мы добавили на прошлой итерации), печатаем его и добавляем уже его дочерние узлы в очередь и так далее.

Comment: Вы когда пытаетесь разобраться в `tree_out_width` абстрагируйтесь от очереди. Вам не важно, что происходит **внутри** всех этих `queue_front`, `queue_pop` и так далее. Вам важно, как их действия видны **снаружи**, рассматривайте их как черный ящик. Т. е. у вас функция `queue_front` возвращает первый элемент в очереди, все. *Как* она это делает — не важно, важно что возвращает. Иначе вы утонете в деталях. Учитесь абстрагироваться.

Comment: @eanmos Ого, спасибо.Уже понятнее.Но, хотел бы спросить еще..Наверное, глупый вопрос , но всё же.Почему q->head->ptr; , а не просто q->head в ф-ции queue_front?

Comment: @Yuikus, потому что `tree_out_width()` работает с узлами дерева, а не очереди. Для ее удобства и сделана функция `queue_front()` (без которой, на самом деле, все было бы даже проще, просто написали бы `p = ((const tree_t*)(q.head->ptr);` (в общем, издержки инкапсуляции))